# How to implement Twitter oAuth in Backbonejs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, twitter-oauth

I am implementing Twitter oAuth in Backbonejs and Nodejs. I have Node api calls

```
app.get('/api/auth/twitter', function(req, res){});
app.get('/api/auth/twitter/callback', function(req, res, next){});
```

If I make the call directly from my browser, then I can get a callback from Twitter.

If I have a direct link in my html

```
<a href="/api/auth/twitter">Login with Twitter</a>
```

Then I get a call back. But do not know how to return to Backbone model

But if I use the Model-View method of Backbonejs, then nothing...

```
window.SignInWithTwitterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function(){
        return '/api/auth/twitter';
    },
    defaults: {
        loggedInStatus: false,
        user_id: ''
     }
});
```

I just call

```
this.model.fetch();
```

Please help....